# What's the highest suggested speed sign worldwide?

Tags: driving, road-signs

On some roads, suggested (not compulsory) speed signs are posted. What's the highest (fastest) suggested speed sign worldwide?

[E.g.](https://www.ornikar.com/code/cours/panneaux/indication/vitesse-conseillee):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of such a sign?

Comment: Highest speed or highest altitude?

Comment: @Berend Good point, highest speed.

Comment: @jcaron example added

Comment: I saw a suggested speed sign at some point in the last few months that was equal to the mandatory limit, which I thought was odd, but I don't remember where it was or what the mandatory limit was.  It might have been 50 or 60 km/h but I think it was higher.

Comment: In France, there are no signs for that, but on dual-carriage roads with at least 3 lanes, there is a **minimum** (not recommended) speed of 90 km/h on the leftmost lane.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a trivia question, not a question about a travel problem

Comment: I see  2 "Needs details or clarity" close votes, could you please tell me what I should clarify or detail?

Comment: @Midavalo https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factoids are on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Suggested speed 130 km/h in Germany maybe?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMpCVm.png]

Answer (score 1):

[Sheikh Khalifa bin Zayed Road](https://www.thenationalnews.com/uae/transport/speed-limit-for-new-abu-dhabi-motorway-set-at-160kph-1.700188) in the United Arab Emirates.

160km/hour, aka 99.4 miles/hour.

I don't believe they are still in place, but for a period around 2015 the Nürburgring Nordschleife ("North loop") racetrack in Nürburg, Germany used to include [sections with 250kph and 200kph speed limits](https://www.bridgetogantry.com/nurburgring-speedlimits-making-sense-of-the-mess/).

Comment: That's a speed *limit*, not a suggested speed though?

Comment: Very cool, never heard of the 200+kph, you're welcome to migrate it to https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/177092/1810