# What's the highest (fastest) posted mandatory maximum speed limit sign worldwide?

Tags: driving, factoids, road-signs

I wonder what the highest (fastest) posted mandatory maximum speed limit sign is worldwide, now or in the past.

Comment: The word "mandatory" means something is mandated or required. Signs that mandate a particular speed are either vanishingly rare, or nonexistent...I've never seen one. Instead, it seems likely that you mean to ask about signs that establish the highest speed that may be driven, in other words, the sign notes a speed _limit_. Is that correct?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica good point, fixed, thanks!

Comment: There are roads with no speed limit at all. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_limit#Roads_without_speed_limits

Comment: According to Wikipedia ([Speed limits in Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_limits_in_Italy)), Italian law allows for motorway speed limits of 150 km/h under certain conditions, but no motorway operator has imposed such a limit, so this is a comment rather than an answer.  The maximum limit actually imposed is 130, which is [the most common maximum in western Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:European_Speed_Limits.svg).

Comment: I see a few "Needs details or clarity" close votes, could you please tell me what I should clarify or detail?

Comment: Are you asking about the maximum speed allowed, or the minimum speed required?

Comment: @jcaron thanks, good catch, maximum.

Comment: Your question should ask if the mandatory limit is imposed by a legal authority or a self imposed restriction.

Answer (score 7):

There are speed limit signs posted on the [Node 1 (aka *Unity*)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(ISS_module)) aft hatch of the [*USOS (US Orbital Segment)*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Orbital_Segment) of the [*ISS (International Space Station)*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station):

[image: Photograph of NASA Astronaut Ellen Ochoa posing in front of the 17500 mph and 28000 km/h speed limit signs on the International Space Station]

They read 17500 mph and 28000 km/h, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

There were (and maybe still are) dynamic 140 (kph) speed limit signs on the A2 motorway in Germany. They were mildly controversial because although there is no overall permanent speed limit, there is a recommend maximum speed of 130 kph.

Answer (score 2):

Since  2011-01-01, the maximum speed on Polish motorways has been 140 km/h, previously it was 130 km/h.

[image]

There were tests for 140 km/h in Germany (2004-??) and Austria (2018-2020) on motorways.

In July 2021 the highest known speed driven on a German moterway was 417 km/h over a 10 km distance between Berlin and Magdeburg (as compaired to the maximun known speed of a Formel 1 race of 370 km/h).

---

**Sources**:

- [Autobahn (Polen) – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autobahn_(Polen))

> Seit dem 1. Januar 2011 beträgt die Höchstgeschwindigkeit auf polnischen Autobahnen 140 km/h, zuvor galten 130 km/h.

- [Tempolimits in Polen | ADAC - Autobahnen: 140km/h](https://www.adac.de/reise-freizeit/reiseplanung/reiseziele/polen/uebersicht/tempolimits/)
- [2022-01-21: Tschechischer Millionär rast mit Tempo 417 über deutsche Autobahn - Virales Video](https://www.pnp.de/nachrichten/panorama/Tschechischer-Millionaer-rast-mit-Tempo-417-in-Bugatti-ueber-deutsche-Autobahn-4218412.html)

Comment: For readers who may be unfamiliar with the Polish sign, it shows default speed limits that apply when a road isn't otherwise marked. It means that the speed limit in towns and cities is 50 km/h between 5 a.m. and 11 p.m. and 60 otherwise. For cars, small trucks, and motorcycles, outside towns, the limit is 90 on 2-lane roads, 100 on 4-lane roads and 2-lane expressways, 120 on 4-lane expressways, and 140 on motorways.  The column on the right applies to large trucks, cars with trailers, buses, and vehicles with hazardous materials. I don't know what the asterisk means.

Comment: Also, 417 km/h is 6.95 km/minute or 115.833 m/s.  Dividing the distance by the speed gives 1.439 minutes or 86.331 seconds.

Comment: @phoog from the wikipedia metadata of the file: Buses with special permission can drive 100 km/h; buses without permission – 80 km/h only. ; These signs are found on border crossings in Europe so that the drivers know what the general speed limits are in effect in the country they are entering.

Comment: Thanks for the information on the asterisk.  The signs are fairly useless, however, as they are too small and convey too much information.  Most such signs are rather simpler than this one (no distinction based on lane count), and I find it nearly impossible to digest them as I'm driving by (if I don't miss them altogether).  They probably work as a reminder for those who are already familiar with the speed laws, which is of course most people, but for others it's really necessary to look up the speed limits separately before the trip.

Comment: @phoog: Schengen creates a bit of an oddity here. Normally, you have to slow down at border crossings, so you have ample time to read the signs. Of course, that does not apply within the Schengen area, so the signs are somewhat less useful. But around where I live, for example, there are many French↔︎German border crossings which have not been remodeled. The turnpikes and guard booths have been removed and obviously, there is no personnel present, but the separation systems, speed bumps, and tight corners designed to slow down traffic are still there, so you can easily read the signs.

Comment: @JörgWMittag but the signs at controlled borders are always _after_ the checkpoint, at which time I am concerned about rejoining the flow of traffic, paying more attention to vehicles and directional signs and safe acceleration than to the sign showing the default speed limits.  I've tried to develop the habit of saying "50, 80, 100, 130" or whatever as I pass the sign, but I often miss it, and I can't imagine that I would get anything useful from the Polish sign if the first time I saw it was on the roadside at the border.

Comment: @phoog As a traveller, it is their responsibility to **adere** to the laws of the country they are in. The signs are there to inform those travelling what the speed limits are. Should you choose to **igore** this information (for what ever reason) does not change the fact that you will be held resposible for any violation of those laws. A judge will not care **in any way shape or form** for the excuses that you have provided in your previous comments.

Comment: @phoog Sorry, but as someone who acts as a experienced traveller, that doesn't understand such **fundanmental basics**, should reconsider giving advice to others.

Comment: @MarkJohnson You misunderstand completely. I'm not ignoring anything wilfully, I'm just complaining that the system for imparting the information is inadequate.  Notice how I said that people unfamiliar with speed laws in Europe should "look up the speed limits separately before the trip."  I'm not offering excuses to anyone, much less to a judge.

Answer (score 1):

In Saudi Arabia, the speed limit was increased to 140 km/h in many highways , the previous speed was 120 km/h with a +10% allowance for speed radar which is not applicable for the 140 highways.

[image]